# Firemonkey Android Width = 0

Tags: delphi, height, width, firemonkey

I'm doing a small app, all is ok on Windows.

In the formshow I create a menu and use `ClientWidth` and `ClientHeight` to insert item in this menu with the good size.

I see when I run it to Android that FormShow was called before FormCreate, ok I see why on another topic, then in both my `ClientWidth` and `ClientHeight` are 0.

If I move the create of the menu behind a `OnClick` event on a Button in the main form that's ok.

So I use the `Screen.Width` and `Screen.Height` which works, but is this what we need to do? That's a little strange ...

Thanks

Comment: What are you using the Width value for? You may need to account for changes in Width, so you could use the OnResize event, for example

Comment: You are right, I do it after post my question here and it works perfectly ! :)